# PHP5 static keyword and usage

Tags: php, static

The `static` keyword is known to be a free agent.

You can declare a method "static" either by writing:

```
protected static function foo() {
// lots of self:: code in here
}
```

Or:

```
static protected function bar() {
// lots of self:: code in here
}
```

I just came across code that read:

```
static protected static function foobar() {
// lots of self:: code in here
}
```

Surely it's a typo from the original author, **but why is PHP accepting this as a valid statement?**

---

**UPDATE** The version in question is **PHP 5.2.16**. I just confirmed, this is valid too:

```
static static static public static function foobar() {
// lots ...
}
```

Comment: Because PHP interpreter is not best in the universe :(
But it's flexible so we can torment it every day to do our bidding :)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in previous versions of PHP which has been fixed. Testing it in PHP 5.3 yields

> **Fatal error:** Multiple static modifiers are not allowed

**EDIT:** thanks to Matt Gibson for the find, this was indeed a bug that was [fixed somewhere in the PHP 5.3 branch](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=246130).

Comment: @Linus Kleen: Yeah, I was searching but nothing came up. Perhaps they found it on their own and quietly fixed it. Sneaky, much ;)

Comment: @Linus @BoltClock http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=246130 (yes, I was bored :) )

Comment: @BoltClock Can you put this in your answer, so I can accept? And thank you for productively wasting your time, @Matt.

Comment: @Linus No problem. Got to have something to do while I'm waiting for long queries to finish :)